# Execute code at the same time everyday in an MacOS App

Tags: swift, macos

I am writing an application that toggles the Do Not Disturb feature on MacOS. I'm running into an issue with this because MacOS automatically toggles the feature off every night at midnight. I don't think there's a way to programmatically prevent this, so I'm trying to just re-enable it at midnight every night.

Is there a way to execute a piece of code every night at midnight exactly regardless of if the computer goes to sleep in Swift 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register for `NSCalendarDayChanged` notification.

If the computer is asleep at midnight you could also register for `NSWorkspaceDidWake`.

Comment: Awesome. I used this followed by
`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` which gave me exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!